# Bootstrap 4 - How to hide a container on laptop and smaller but show it on desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am developing the header of a website. The searchbar looks like this in full hd desktop:

[image]

But on laptop view (width: 1280px) it looks like this:

[image]

So I try to hide the last column for laptop view and smaller views, but there seems to be no way, since **Extra large** is defined as **>= 1200px** and my laptop screen is 1280px width. Why is my tiny laptop screen already considered as "Extra large" ?

Bootstrap claims to be a "mobile first" framework. However, judging from the breakpoints, it's a mobile-only layout framework

Do I have to use media queries and custom css classes to hide it, or is there still a bootstrap 4 way?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the breakpoints to your liking:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid

Adjust the values in the sass to the ones you want / need.

Example:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 600px,
  md: 800px,
  lg: 1000px,
  xl: 1281px // or what ever else you want for extra large
);
```

Comment: Which file do I have to edit? There is no info about it.

Comment: The file is called _variables.scss, it's in the scss folder of the sources. The grid breakpoints start in line 198 for the 4.4.1 version. You might also want to edit the container-max-widths below in case you are not using container-fluid. Afterwards recompile the css with any sass compiler.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the file and compiled it with a tool called "Scout-App". Git showed me that it resulted in the files *dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css* and *dist/css/bootstrap.css* being changed. However, I only use `bootstrap.css` in my project, do I also need to load `bootstrap-grid.css` now?

Comment: Can you check your bootstrap.scss file (in the scss folder). There should be a line '@import "grid";'. If this line is there, you only need the bootstrap.css, it will include the grid. The reason both files get changed is because you could, if you wanted, only use the grid as standalone without the other bootstrap css.

Comment: yes the import line is there. Now I see, thank you!