# Bootstrap 4 - understanding $grid-breakpoints and $container-max-widths

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I need to add more breakpoints to support laptops and desktop, since the default bootstrap 4 breakpoints are only made for mobile and it is not possible to hide containers only for laptop screens with a screen width of for example 1280px, but show it on desktop, because the max breakpoint (xl) is 1200px. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753330/bootstrap-4-how-to-hide-a-container-on-laptop-and-smaller-width-1280).

You need to edit `scss/_variables.scss` to achieve this.

```
// Grid breakpoints
//
// Define the minimum dimensions at which your layout will change,
// adapting to different screen sizes, for use in media queries.

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
) !default;

@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");


// Grid containers
//
// Define the maximum width of `.container` for different screen sizes.

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```

It says: "Grid breakpoints: Define the minimum dimensions at which your layout will change`

So they set the minimum for **xl** to **1200px** and they defined the maximum to **1140px**.

In my understanding if the window is **1199px**, then it switches to `lg`.
But why is the maximum size of xl **1140px**? What happens with the 59px between 1199px and 1140px ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the difference between the **grid** and a **container**.
If you set the **grid** xl breakpoint to 1200px and the **container**-max-width to 1140px, it simply means you will have a white space of 30px on each side of the container.

[image: example image]

If you do not want this white space, use `.container-fluid` instead.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#containers

See also this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/v07Lynqo/7/